# Expandable jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hoping someone can help me with this as client side styling isn't my general area of expertise. I have a dialog box that displays data for a client. They want to be able to click a button on the dialog and have it expand (preferably like a slide animation) and show hidden content to the right. This content on the right also needs to scroll separate from the part on the left (which should not scroll). Think form in the left section that fits on page, and item history on the right which could potentially be long enough to scroll.

I feel like this should be possible but so far I haven't been able to get it to work and as I said client styling isn't generally my area. If anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated.

Here is a mock-up showing generally what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (if so i can annotate and explain it)

updated - added scroll, overflow-y

```js
$('blockwrapper, hiddenblockshow').click(function() {
 $('hiddenblock').toggleClass('hiddenblockshow');
});
```

```css
blockwrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
mainblock {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 10%, 1);
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
}
hiddenblock {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 30%, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.hiddenblockshow {
  margin-left: 100%;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockwrapper>
    <hiddenblock>Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff Some secret stuff</hiddenblock>
  <mainblock>Some stuff<br>click me</mainblock>
</blockwrapper>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/5ya2m39e/2/

A non-flexbox version

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/5ya2m39e/

Comment: Essentially yes with some minor glitches like the content of the animated div briefly popping in front of the stationary one when you click it and there is no separate scroll in the right portion but yes that is the basic functionality I am looking for.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that thanks. Yes that is the functionality I am looking for as long as it is compatible with jquery ui dialog box which is what I am using. Here is a simple set up with a jquery ui dialog https://plnkr.co/edit/GgyiYITpfvhV0iCbsauz?p=preview

Comment: I had a look and I'm sure it's possible to customize it as you want with a bit of work. I'm not all that familiar with jquery ui so I don't know if there is an easier, built in method.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will probably play with it more tomorrow and if I need clarification I will post here.

Comment: Quick question, how backwards compatible is this with older browsers? Unfortunately my client is still using SharePoint 2010 and it defaults to IE=8 mode and I am wondering if these flex containers will break. I am out of the office until monday so I can't test for now but if this doesn't work, do you know of another way to accomplish this that would be supported by the older browser settings. Thanks

Comment: Good question, flex still has issues between even the newest browsers. I rewrote it a little to rely on positioning, it might have a better chance at working with IE8 but I can't say for certain. New fiddle is on the bottom of answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the Dialog by using

```
 $(document).on("click","#expand_btn",function(){

  $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "width", 500 );

 })
```

Comment: Thanks this may be useful but still doesn't accomplish everything I am looking for. I would like it to slide open similar to how an accordion does except to the right instead of vertical. Also I need a way to scroll the content on the right separate from the left.

Comment: Then set width using jquery animate function